# Mysql select selects 3 times each value

Tags: mysql

I run this query:

```
SELECT routes.route_number, routes.frequency 
FROM routes, 
  (SELECT proportion FROM operation_proportions WHERE operator='Venture Travel') AS Prop 
WHERE routes.route_number 
  IN (SELECT route FROM operation_proportions WHERE operator='Venture Travel');
```

and the result I get is:
[image: result]

As you can see, each value is selected 3 times for some reason which I cannot figure out. I have cut out some parts of the sql statement for testing purposes because the result I was getting wasn't the expected one.

Here is the full statement I'm trying to get to work:

```
SELECT SUM((Prop.proportion / 100) * routes.frequency) AS TotalJourneys 
FROM routes, 
  (SELECT proportion FROM operation_proportions WHERE operator='Venture Travel') AS Prop 
WHERE routes.route_number 
  IN (SELECT route FROM operation_proportions WHERE operator='Venture Travel');
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is calculate the total bus routes the operator called Venture Travel is doing per hour. Proportion is a value between 0-100 (in this case only 100 and 50 are used so that's not the problem) and frequency is the number of times per hour the route is done by a bus.

So my end goal is in a few words: Sum up each frequency * (proportion / 100) for the routes that are operated by Venture Travel.

Sorry I didn't explain something correctly or missed out useful data, please tell me if you need more information to help me. Thanks.

Comment: Does this query return 3 rows? `SELECT proportion FROM operation_proportions WHERE operator='Venture Travel';`

Comment: Your use of subqueries is most likely the problem. I don't think it is necessary in this case. Try using a simple join instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the reason for the inline view `Prop` ? Based on the description of the observed behavior, we suspect that the the inline view query

```
         SELECT proportion
           FROM operation_proportions
          WHERE operator = 'Venture Travel'
```

is returning three rows. And each of those three rows is being "matched" to each row returned from `routes`. The result from the query is a Cartesian product... every row returned from `routes` matched to every row from returned for the inline view.

The first query in the question could be equivalently written as.

```
 SELECT r.route_number
      , r.frequency
   FROM routes r
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT p.proportion 
            FROM operation_proportions p
           WHERE p.operator = 'Venture Travel'
        ) q
  WHERE r.route_number IN ( SELECT o.route 
                              FROM operation_proportions o
                             WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
                          )
```

We could eliminate the join to the inline view, so that we only get one copy of each row from `routes`...

```
SELECT r.route_number
     , r.frequency
  FROM routes r
 WHERE r.route_number IN ( SELECT o.route 
                             FROM operation_proportions o
                            WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
                         )
```

---

If the values of the `route` column are UNIQUE in `operations_proportions` for the `operator = 'Venture Travel'` rows, we could use a JOIN operation to return an equivalent result.

```
SELECT r.route_number
     , r.frequency
  FROM routes r
  JOIN operation_proportions o
    ON o.route = r.route_number
 WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
```

And that will let us return the value of `proportion` column from the matching row, and include that in an expression

```
 SELECT r.route_number
      , r.frequency
      , o.proportion
      , r.frequency * o.proportion / 100.0
   FROM routes r
   JOIN operation_proportions o
     ON o.route = r.route_number
  WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
```

And then we can use an aggregate function to "collapse" of the rows to get a total

```
 SELECT SUM( r.frequency * o.proportion / 100.0 ) AS TotalJourneys
   FROM routes r
   JOIN operation_proportions o
     ON o.route = r.route_number
  WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
```

---

If `route` isn't unique from `operation_proportions`, we can address that. We would just need to determine whether we want to return all of the matching rows, or *which* of those rows to return.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I can understand too what I was doing wrong, great explanation.

Comment: @ZedZerg: My answers sometimes tend towards being rather lengthy. My sincere apologies to the "try this" answer enthusiasts. It seemed like you were interested in why the query was doing what it was doing, I tried to answer that question. And I followed up with an explanation of how we might go about writing a query that does what it seemed like you were trying to achieve. I hope that this answer goes beyond just fixing this one query, and provides a pattern that you can keep in your SQL toolbelt.

Answer (score 1):

The `SUM()` function is usually used in the context of aggregation.  Hence, I propose that you intend to compute some statistics for each route number in your table.  This is my guess as to what you want here:

```
SELECT r.route_number,
       SUM((o.proportion / 100) * r.frequency) AS TotalJourneys 
FROM routes r
INNER JOIN operation_proportions o
    ON r.route_number = o.route
GROUP BY r.route_number
WHERE o.operator = 'Venture Travel'
```

Comment: My answer was downvoted as well. The query in this answer seems reasonable to me, absent a schema definition, example data, and desired resultset, we're just guessing. But this seems like a reasonable guess. +10